# Program is only pulling info from one line of my array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue where I am getting the wrong info pulled from my array from user input. What have I done wrong? I also need to pull all the info gathered at the end and give it as a summary.

**//code:**

```
    public class stateSystem {  

    static int length;

    public static int stateData(String stateData[][],String state)
      {
         int position = -1;
          boolean found = false;
          for (int i=0; i<stateSystem.length && !found; i++)
          {
              if(stateData[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(state))
                  position=i;              
          }
          return position;
      }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
       
        String[][] stateInformation = new String[][] {
            {"Alabama", "Yellowhammer", "Camelia"},
            {"Alaska", "Willow Ptarmigan", "Forget-Me-Not"},
            {"Arizona", "Cactus Wren", "Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
            {"Arkansas", "Mockingbird", "Apple Blossom"},
            {"California", "California Valley Quail", "Golden Poppy"},
            {"Colorado", "Lark Bunting", "Rocky Mountain Columbine"},
            {"Connecticut", "Robin", "Mountain Laurel"},
            {"Delaware", "Blue Hen Chicken", "Peach Blossom"},
            {"Florida", "Mockingbird", "Orange Blossom"},
            {"Georgia", "Brown Thrasher", "Cherokee Rose"},
            {"Hawaii", "Nene", "Hawaiian Hibiscus"},
            {"Idaho", "Mountain Bluebird", "Syringa, mock orange"},
            {"Illinois", "Cardinal", "Violet"},
            {"Indiana", "Cardinal", "Peony"},
            {"Iowa", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Wild Praire Rose"},
            {"Kansas", "Western Meadowlark", "Sunflower"},
            {"Kentucky", "Cardinal", "Goldenrod"},           
            {"Louisiana", "Eastern Brown Pelican", "Magnolia"},
            {"Maine", "Chickadee", "Pine Cone and Tassel"},
            {"Maryland", "Baltimore Oriole", "Black-Eyed Susan"},
            {"Massachusetts", "Chickadee", "Mayflower"},
            {"Michigan", "Robin", "Apple Blossom"},
            {"Minnesota", "Common Loon", "Pink and White Lady's Slippper"},
            {"Mississippi", "Mockingbird", "Magnolia"},
            {"Missouri", "Bluebird", "Hawthorn"},
            {"Montana", "Western Meadowlark", "Bitterroot"},
            {"Nebraska", "Western Meadowlark", "Goldenrod"},
            {"Nevada", "Mountain Bluebird", "Sagebrush"},
            {"New Hampshire", "Purple Finch", "Purple Lilac"},
            {"New Jersey", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Violet"},
            {"New Mexico", "Roadrunner", "Yucca Flower"},
            {"New York", "Bluebird", "Rose"},
            {"North Carolina", "Cardinal", "Flowering Dogwood"},
            {"North Dakota", "Western Meadowlark", "Wild Praire Rose"},
            {"Ohio", "Cardinal", "Scarlet Carnation"},
            {"Oklahoma","Scissor-tailed Flycatcher","Oklahoma Rose"},            
            {"Oregon", "Western Meadowlark", "Oregon Grape"},
            {"Pennsylvania", "Ruffed Grouse", "Mountain Laurel"},
            {"Rhode Island", "Rhode Island Red", "Violet"},           
            {"South Carolina", "Great Carolina Wren", "Yellow Jessamine"},
            {"South Dakota", "Ring-necked Pheasant", "Pasque Flower"},
            {"Tennessee", "Mockingbird", "Purple Passionflower"},
            {"Texas", "Mockingbird", "Bluebonnet Sp."},
            {"Utah", "Common American Gull", "Sego Lily"},
            {"Vermont", "Hermit Thrush", "Red Clover"},
            {"Virginia","Cardinal"," American Dogwood"},
            {"Washington", "Willow Goldfinch", "Coast Rhododendrum"},
            {"West Virginia", "Cardinal", "Rhododendron"},
            {"Wisconsin", "Robin", "Wood Violet"},
            {"Wyoming", "Western Meadowlark", "Indian Paintbrush"}
        };                   

        ArrayList<String> enteredStates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true){
          
         
    
          System.out.println("Enter a State or None to exit: "); 
          String stateNames = userInput.next();
          
         
           if (stateNames.equalsIgnoreCase ("None")){
             System.out.println ("**** Thank You****"); 
             System.out.println("A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: " );
          
             for(String vistedState : enteredStates) {
                 int stateIndex = stateData(stateInformation, vistedState);
                 
                 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stateInformation[stateIndex]));
             }
             break;
           }
           
           else {
             int position = stateData (stateInformation, stateNames);
             if (position != -1){
               System.out.println("State Bird: " + stateInformation[position][1]);
               System.out.println("State Flower: " + stateInformation[position][2]);
             }
               
               else{ System.out.println("Unrecognized, please enter a new State: ");
             }
           }
        }
      }
  }
```

**//Output:**

Enter a State or None to exit:
Georgia

State Bird: Willow Ptarmigan

State Flower: Forget-Me-Not

Enter a State or None to exit:
Mississippi

State Bird: Willow Ptarmigan

State Flower: Forget-Me-Not

Enter a State or None to exit:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an error in the `stateData` method and were not looking up states correctly. Puelo pointed out some problems with it in his answer, so I won't repeat them here. You were also not adding looked up states to `enteredStates`. Here is amended code that should work fine for you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StateSystem {

    public static int stateData(String stateData[][], String state) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stateData.length; i++) {
            if (stateData[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(state))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] stateInformation = new String[][]{
                {"Alabama", "Yellowhammer", "Camelia"},
                {"Alaska", "Willow Ptarmigan", "Forget-Me-Not"},
                {"Arizona", "Cactus Wren", "Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
                {"Arkansas", "Mockingbird", "Apple Blossom"},
                {"California", "California Valley Quail", "Golden Poppy"},
                {"Colorado", "Lark Bunting", "Rocky Mountain Columbine"},
                {"Connecticut", "Robin", "Mountain Laurel"},
                {"Delaware", "Blue Hen Chicken", "Peach Blossom"},
                {"Florida", "Mockingbird", "Orange Blossom"},
                {"Georgia", "Brown Thrasher", "Cherokee Rose"},
                {"Hawaii", "Nene", "Hawaiian Hibiscus"},
                {"Idaho", "Mountain Bluebird", "Syringa, mock orange"},
                {"Illinois", "Cardinal", "Violet"},
                {"Indiana", "Cardinal", "Peony"},
                {"Iowa", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Wild Praire Rose"},
                {"Kansas", "Western Meadowlark", "Sunflower"},
                {"Kentucky", "Cardinal", "Goldenrod"},
                {"Louisiana", "Eastern Brown Pelican", "Magnolia"},
                {"Maine", "Chickadee", "Pine Cone and Tassel"},
                {"Maryland", "Baltimore Oriole", "Black-Eyed Susan"},
                {"Massachusetts", "Chickadee", "Mayflower"},
                {"Michigan", "Robin", "Apple Blossom"},
                {"Minnesota", "Common Loon", "Pink and White Lady's Slippper"},
                {"Mississippi", "Mockingbird", "Magnolia"},
                {"Missouri", "Bluebird", "Hawthorn"},
                {"Montana", "Western Meadowlark", "Bitterroot"},
                {"Nebraska", "Western Meadowlark", "Goldenrod"},
                {"Nevada", "Mountain Bluebird", "Sagebrush"},
                {"New Hampshire", "Purple Finch", "Purple Lilac"},
                {"New Jersey", "Eastern Goldfinch", "Violet"},
                {"New Mexico", "Roadrunner", "Yucca Flower"},
                {"New York", "Bluebird", "Rose"},
                {"North Carolina", "Cardinal", "Flowering Dogwood"},
                {"North Dakota", "Western Meadowlark", "Wild Praire Rose"},
                {"Ohio", "Cardinal", "Scarlet Carnation"},
                {"Oklahoma", "Scissor-tailed Flycatcher", "Oklahoma Rose"},
                {"Oregon", "Western Meadowlark", "Oregon Grape"},
                {"Pennsylvania", "Ruffed Grouse", "Mountain Laurel"},
                {"Rhode Island", "Rhode Island Red", "Violet"},
                {"South Carolina", "Great Carolina Wren", "Yellow Jessamine"},
                {"South Dakota", "Ring-necked Pheasant", "Pasque Flower"},
                {"Tennessee", "Mockingbird", "Purple Passionflower"},
                {"Texas", "Mockingbird", "Bluebonnet Sp."},
                {"Utah", "Common American Gull", "Sego Lily"},
                {"Vermont", "Hermit Thrush", "Red Clover"},
                {"Virginia", "Cardinal", " American Dogwood"},
                {"Washington", "Willow Goldfinch", "Coast Rhododendrum"},
                {"West Virginia", "Cardinal", "Rhododendron"},
                {"Wisconsin", "Robin", "Wood Violet"},
                {"Wyoming", "Western Meadowlark", "Indian Paintbrush"}
        };
        ArrayList<String> enteredStates = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a State or None to exit: ");
            String stateNameIn = userInput.next();

            if (stateNameIn.equalsIgnoreCase("None")) {
                System.out.println("**** Thank You****");
                System.out.println("A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: ");
                for (String visitedState : enteredStates) {
                    int stateIndex = stateData(stateInformation, visitedState);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stateInformation[stateIndex]));
                }
                break;
            } else {
                int position = stateData(stateInformation, stateNameIn);
                if (position != -1) {
                    System.out.println("State Bird: " + stateInformation[position][1]);
                    System.out.println("State Flower: " + stateInformation[position][2]);
                    enteredStates.add(stateInformation[position][0]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unrecognized, please enter a new State: ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems i can see:

```
for (int i=0; i<stateSystem.length && !found; i++) {
    if(stateData[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(state))
        position=i;              
}
```

First you are using `stateSystem.length` as your stopping point without providing any code how it is used, so this might be a problem. Secondly you are never setting `found` to true once the information was found.

I would probably also either put the assignment inside the loop on the same line as the `if`, or put the whole thing into `{ }`